# Create a html document from result of webclient downloadstring method

Tags: .net, webclient, dom

I want to get html content from a webpage in my windows app.
Im using webclient DownloadString method to get the string content and now I want to store this string result in html document but I am unable to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by HTML document? What do you intend to do with the string?

Comment: Store in htmlDocument class object as i have to get content from the html content.

Comment: could you point a link to the documentation on MSDN on this class?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to download and parse the HTML you are interested in.

It offers several ways to query the HTML, including LINQ and XPath.

Comment: Is there any other inbuilt method so that I can create htmlDocument object from the string result instead of using this Agility Pack. I know about this agility pack but I am trying to find way to create it with inbuilt method

Comment: @Meherzad - The `HtmlDocument` class doesn't expose a constructor or any way (that I could see) to create one from a string. The documentation does say it is intended to be used by the `WebBrowser` control, so I doubt you can.

Comment: @Meherzad, what's you final goal? What do you intend to do with this html document?

Comment: Ok thanks so one last doubt I have that is there any way that i can create html document?

Comment: @Meherzad - I though I explained. Only through the `WebBrowser` control. And you have not explained what you need to do with the HTML.

Comment: I want to get content within the html doc page which Im using in my app.

Comment: @Meherzad - And do what with the content? Just the body? The header as well? As HTML? As text?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("youFileName.html",yourString);
```